# Java-Mysql Connection error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-error-1045

My stack trace:

```
cbs.ui.OverallReportUI btnGenerateBillActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:910)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3923)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1273)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2031)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:718)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:302)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
        at cbs.ui.OverallReportUI.GenerateReport(OverallReportUI.java:219)
        at cbs.ui.OverallReportUI.btnGenerateBillActionPerformed(OverallReportUI.java:153)
        at cbs.ui.OverallReportUI.access$100(OverallReportUI.java:38)
        at cbs.ui.OverallReportUI$2.actionPerformed(OverallReportUI.java:85)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6038)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3260)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
```

Comment: I would suggest not to use the root credentials for DB access. You should create a new user that will be used only by this application for database access.

Comment: Please post your ip and root password so we can all help you with this!

Answer (score 7):

The key text to look at is:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

This is simply a credentials issue. Verify that you can log in with the command line using the same credentials your code is using.